# Get wind direction from raster stack U and V in R

Tags: r, netcdf, rasterstack

I have this NetCDF file (about 130 kb size). I want to get for each day (layer) the wind direction (in meteorological or geographical directions) at every cell.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UxYGJK1-gIgXWZT6tE10bavmiNEpsVx3

I tried:

```
library(raster)

u <- brick("uv_comp.nc", varname = "u10")
v <- brick("uv_comp.nc", varname = "v10")

dirs <- atan2(v[[1]], u[[1]]) / (2*3.14159265) + (0.5 * 360) # for the first layer
```

However, I am not very sure that this method is the correct one. Can anyone confirm, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atan2` gives you a direction in radians, so to convert to degrees you wouldn't do:

```
dirs <- atan2(v[[1]], u[[1]]) / (2*3.14159265) + (0.5 * 360)
```

you do:

```
dirs <- 180 * atan2(v, u) / pi
```

Note here I'm doing all layers at once, using `pi` instead of spelling it out, and multiplying by 180 rather than adding 180 (=0.5*360). This gives degrees from -180 to 180, so maybe you added 180 to get 0 to 360, in which case:

```
dirs = 180 + 180 * atan2(v,u) / pi
```

will give directions from 0 to 360.

You should check the directions are as expected in case you have got `u` and `v` the wrong way round. We've all done it.